# IPhone: Video API: Live video streaming modify

Tags: iphone, video, streaming

I have a question about video stream processing. Is it possible to get access and modify real time video stream during recording (f.e. I want to add some text to video)? I can do this as a preview by getting separate frames, but I'm looking for tool which will allow me to store video with my text in video frames.

Probably there is already some libraries/tools available (but I haven't found any yet).

Answer (score 1):

Try GPUIMAGE library. It can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check AVCam sample code by apple. That might be a starting point.